# Python user defined sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, oop

I am trying to implement a user defined sort function, similar to the python **List sort** as in **list.sort(cmp = None, key = None, reverse = False)** for example.

Here is my code so far

```
from operator import itemgetter

class Sort:
    def __init__(self, sList, key = itemgetter(0), reverse = False):

        self._sList = sList
        self._key = key
        self._reverse = reverse 
        self.sort()

    def sort(self):

        for index1 in range(len(self._sList) - 1):
            for index2 in range(index1, len(self._sList)):

                if self._reverse == True:

                    if self._sList[index1] < self._sList[index2]:
                        self._sList[index1], self._sList[index2] =  self._sList[index2], self._sList[index1]

                else: 

                    if self._sList[index1] > self._sList[index2]:
                        self._sList[index1], self._sList[index2] =  self._sList[index2], self._sList[index1]


List = [[1 ,2],[3, 5],[5, 1]]
Sort(List, reverse = True)
print List
```

I have a really bad time when it comes to the **key** parameter.

More specifically, I would like to know if there is a way to code a list with optional indexes (similar to **foo(*parameters)** ).

I really hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

`key` is a function to convert the item to a criterion used for comparison.

Called with the item as the sole parameter, it returns a comparable value of your choice.

One classical key example for integers stored as string is:

```
lambda x : int(x)
```

so strings are sorted numerically.

In your algorithm, you would have to replace

```
self._sList[index1] < self._sList[index2]
```

by

```
self._key(self._sList[index1]) < self._key(self._sList[index2])
```

so the values computed from items are compared, rather than the items themselves.

note that Python 3 dropped the `cmp` method, and just kept `key` method.

also note that in your case, using `itemgetter(0)` as the key function works for *subscriptable* items such as `list` (sorting by first item only) or `str` (sorting by first character only).